# TChart не рисует график (RAD Studio, C++)

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте

Вот на простом примере

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Series1->Add(100,200,clRed);
}
```

Компилятор все принимает без ругани, при нажатии на **Button3** на осях **TChart**'a отмечаются метки 100 по **Y** и 200 по **Х**, но вот красной линии нету. Ф-ю **AddXY** тоже пробовал указав все необходимые параметры для нее, никакого толку.

Как же заставить его рисовать красную линию в точку 100х200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было активировать функцию **DrawBetweenPoints**